# Rest API Django não funciona

Tags: python, api, django, restful

estou com um problema no `Python/Django`. As tabelas `school` e `school_application_info` são relacionadas. No entanto, não existe registro com alguns `school_id` na `school_application_info`. Por isso acrescentei `null=True, blank=True` ficando desta maneira:

```
school = models.OneToOneField(School, related_name='school_application_info', null=True, blank=True)
```

Depois fiz os comandos do Django migrations:

```
./manage.py makemigrations
./manage.py migrate
```

Mas não está funcionando e gera um erro:

```
SchoolViewSet: ErrorResponse - status:400, resp:{'school_application_info': [u'This field may not be null.']}
```

Comment: qual biblioteca você está utilizando para api rest??

Comment: Estou usando django-rest-framework.

Comment: Lucas, teria como você compartilhar o código do view que recebe a chamada?

Answer (score 2):

`PrimaryKeyRelatedField` pode ser usado para representar a relação usando a sua chave primária:

```
class SchoolSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    school_application_info = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(allow_null=True)

    class Meta:
         model = School
```

O argumento `allow_null` se for definido como `True`, o campo aceitará valores Nulo ou strings vazias para relacionamentos nulos. O padrão é `False`.

[Veja na documentação](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield)